# Is there a way to automatically launch and search the default Video app in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Windows 8 store apps can register the type of protocols they can handle. This works great for apps that can handle web URLs (Http....) or email apps (mailto:...), etc.

A lot of apps also specify their special protocols. For example, the Windows store handles "ms-windows-store", and you can, for example, launch the app and search with

ms-windows-store:Search?query=hello

My question is whether anyone knows the format that the msft video app uses. It's activation protocol is "microsoftvideo:", but I haven't been able to figure out what (if any) format of inputs it takes. For example, the following does NOT work.

microsoftvideo:Search?query=hello

As a second question, does anyone know the formats available to other popular apps? I can launch Netflix with "netflix:", but haven't been able to figure out if I can search right away as well.

Thanks.

Comment: As found in the link provided by Youngjae, here's official documentation for launching the Maps app http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj635237.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please read StackOverflow similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13332190/361100).

Without registering any name, Package Family Name can be used to execute another app.
Please kindly read [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974767.aspx).

And, about naming protocols which is called URI scheme, please kindly read this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

And, about the `?query=`, I think you may not intend Search Contract. In this case, you may not know unless they(developer of another app) opened the information because it is defined by own.

Comment: I would like to do more than launch another app. Specifically, I would like to launch the video app and point to a specific TV show or Movie. Yes, I am asking whether people know about undocumented parameters that msft apps are accepting.

Comment: Someone figured out that the Windows Store app accepts "Search?query={0}". Someone else might know what other default msft apps also accept.

Comment: @George // Your intend is totally dependent on the another app. Hope that you get the information (but it would be hard, as you know). Microsoft apps are also upgraded little by little so that someday your action (hopefully) can be implemented.