# Pass data between two winRT apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there a way for apps running on WinRT to send information between them? I know about WinRT's sandboxing and the reasons behind it, but is there some mechanism for two apps created by the same author to pass data between each other?

Answer (score 0):

This was announced for Windows 10 only. You can see the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.getpublishercachefolder.aspx) for this already.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But is there any event firing mechanism like application event in traditional windows application?

Comment: There is a way to launch other apps with a specific URI where you can use the URI parameter to pass some content to the other app. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330858/launch-another-windows-store-app
But it is not possible to share files - except you are using the SHARE functionality of the charms bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean running 2 apps at the same time by split-screen, you could consider  using socket to communicate between these 2 apps. But you need to ensure the port is not occupied.

The classes you need to use:

[StreamSocketListener class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701492.aspx)

[StreamSocket class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br226882)

[Article to reference: How to connect with a stream socket (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in windows 8.1 applications because these are sandbox applications